# Share Point online in term store manager get error

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, term-store

I upload jQuery and taxonomy JavaScript files to the Site Assets library in the host web and also registers script links on the web using `UserCustomActions`.

After this, when I change anything and click save on Term Store Management page I get the following errors in console window and also the page gets blank:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_behaviors' of null @msajaxbundle.js:1
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null  @ termstoremanager.js:4252

Doesanyone know a solution for this errors and why this errors are coming?

Comment: Could you share your ScriptLinks. Sometimes, when you make some syntax error in ScriptLink, it can cause whole page errors.